# Vault Token Helper not being detected?

Tags: go, devops, alpine-linux, hashicorp-vault

**Problem:**

I have three files in a `vault:0.10.2` docker image at the following locations:

`/home/myuser/token_helper`: A token helper binary in Go that implements the token helper interface according to [this documentation](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/building-a-vault-token-helper)

`/home/myuser/vault_start`: A Go script that runs `os.exec("vault", "operator", "init")` and `os.exec("vault", "server", "-config=myconfig.hcl")`

`/home/myuser/.vault`: The token helper config file specifying the token helper binary location, and I've exported `VAULT_CONFIG_PATH` to point to this path. The file reads `token_helper = "/home/myuser/token_helper"`.

The problem I'm seeing is while running the `vault_start` script, I get the following error:

```
failed to get token helper: error expanding config path "": exec: "getent": executable file not found in $PATH
```

**Debugging Done So Far**:

This error doesn't seem to be correct. `which getent` returns `/usr/bin/getent`, and the image `$PATH` contains it, proving that both exist. In addition, the config path is not `""`, it's set as `/home/myuser/.vault` but Vault detects it as empty apparently.

I've traced that error output to [this file](https://github.com/ebekker/hashicorp-vault/blob/master/command/config.go#L59) in Vault's `command` directory: . According to that block of code, it only errors out when `$HOME` is not set, but I've confirmed that `$HOME` is set in the shell.

In addition, I've specified everything that Vault has asked in order to implement the token helper according to [this document](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/building-a-vault-token-helper), but it doesn't seem to be detecting the config file to run it. This seems to be an error with Vault, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out, it was because the `os.exec("vault", "operator", "init")` line did not inherit the `VAULT_CONFIG_PATH` variable setting from the host, and so it was empty.

The following shows how to give `os.Exec` environment variables during it's run:

```
    vaultInitCmd := exec.Command("vault", "operator", "init")
    vaultInitCmd.Env = []string{
    fmt.Sprintf(`VAULT_ADDR=%s`, addr),
    fmt.Sprintf(`VAULT_CONFIG_PATH=%s`, `/home/myuser/.vault`)}
```

Comment: Hey I am having the same problem but I am doing this in Nodejs so basically I am executing child process using exec() and I pass all the env variables required for Vault but getting same error as above. How did you solve the above problem as I am not sure about the value of VAULT_CONFIG_PATH when I pass the value as /usr/local/bin/vault as that is binary file for vault but it shows me "illegal char found , file not valid ..... "

Comment: @SOURAVKUMAR have you tried printing VAULT_CONFIG_PATH before passing the env vars into exec()? If it's not empty, then it might be *how* you're passing in the env vars into exec()

Comment: Oh I waited for so many days to just answer your comment and potentially anyone who will be getting here after this error but wasn't able to comment due to somehow my reputations were not enough. So, regarding your comment, VAULT_CONFIG_PATH was fine , actually the problem was in HOME env variable it was empty before passing to my exec() method, so I set it to the required path and now this getent error was gone and you saved many hours of debugging. I found my answer in your question description itself. thanks.